# while iterating over the directory, test to see if the items are files or directories

Tags: shell-script

First, I am newer than new, I'm sorry this is so long, but the forum rules ask for details.

Also sorry this is printing out weird.

Here is what I am trying to do: I am stuck on part (B)

> The script you create must use only relative paths for all paths in
>   the code. You must assume that the script is being run from the ~
>   directory.
>
> (A) Create a shell script that loops through all items in a directory
>   given by the user using the "read" builtin. The script must validate
>   the input and use a loop to only allow the script to proceed after the
>   validation is complete. It must validate that the directory given is a
>   directory.
>
> (B) The script, while iterating over the items in the directory,
>   should test the items to see if they are directories or files.
>
> - (B.1) If they are directories then the script needs to loop over the directory and count the number of items inside of the directory (not
>     recursively). The script needs to output both the name of the
>     directory and the number of files (and folders) inside of it to the
>     same line of a file named "~/sorter/directory_listing.txt".
> - (B.2) If they are files they need to be examined for size using du with human readable output. Your script will have to write the size
>     followed by a space then the file name to a new line of the file
>     "~/sorter/files_and_sizes.txt".
>
> (C) After the loop finishes the files_and_sizes.txt file needs to be
>   sorted human readable then output to a file ~/sorter/files_sorted.txt
>   The directory_listing.txt file needs to be sorted reverse by the
>   number of items in the directory and output to a file named
>   ~/sorter/dir_reverse.txt

My attempt:

```
read -p "Please enter a directory " chosen_dir

while [[ ! -d "$chosen_dir" ]]
do
 echo Please enter a valid directory && read chosen_dir
done

for i in $chosen_dir/*;

    do
        counter=$((counter+1))
        if [ -d "$chosen_dir" ]; then
            ls "$chosen_dir" | wc -l > sorter/directory_listing.txt
        else
            if [ -f "$chosen_dir" ]; then
                du -sh "$chosen_dir"/* > sorter/files_and_sizes.txt
        fi
    done
```

RESULT:

```
blahblah@vm1:~$ ./taratest.sh
Please enter a directory testsort
./taratest.sh: line 26: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./taratest.sh: line 26: `    done'
```

When I remove the `done` I get this ….

NEW RESULT:

```
blahblah@vm1:~$ ./taratest.sh
Please enter a directory testsort
./taratest.sh: line 27: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

THEN: I searched on here for
while iterating over the directory, test to see if the items are files or directories in bash

and changed to THIS:

first part of script, then…

```
for i in "$chosen_dir"/*

do
    [ -f "$chosen_dir" ] && echo "is File"

    [ -d "$chosen_dir" ] && echo "is Directory"


done
```

#### I KNOW THE OUTPUT IS NOT WHAT'S IN THE DIRECTIONS, I AM ECHOING JUST FOR TEST PURPOSES

RESULTS:

```
Please enter a directory testsort

is Directory

is Directory

is Directory

is Directory
```

### 2 are files & 2 are dirs., so why is it saying 4 dirs

```
blahblah@vm1:~$ ls -lh testsort
total 8.0K
drwxrwxrwx 2 blahblah student 68 Jun  4 17:41 dir1
drwxrwxrwx 2 blahblah student 68 Jun  4 17:41 dir2
-rwxrwxrwx 1 blahblah student  0 Jun  4 17:41 file1.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 blahblah student  0 Jun  4 17:41 file2.txt
```

Any guidance on solutions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `for i in "$chosen_dir"/*` so your loop variable is `$i` i.e. you should be doing `[ -f "$i" ]` and so on. As it stands, you are repeatedly testing the parent directory `"$chosen_dir"` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have this construct:

```
for [stuff]; do
   if [test]; then
       [stuff]
   else
       if [test]; then
          stuff
   fi
done
```

You have two nested `if`s, which is fine, but you only terminate one of them with `fi`.  You need to do one of these:

```
# Alternative one:
for [stuff]; do
   if [test]; then
       [stuff]
   else
       if [test]; then
          stuff
       fi
   fi
done

# Alternative two
for [stuff]; do
   if [test]; then
       [stuff]
   elif [test]; then
       stuff
   fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Another problem with this is that you (correctly) quote the variable when you test it with `-d`, but fail to quote it in the `for` loop.

Instead of:

```
for i in $chosen_dir/*;

    do
```

Use:

```
for f in "$chosen_dir"/*; do
```

(The name change and whitespace change are style points; the added double quotes are important.)

---

I don't know what you're trying to use the counter for, because you never actually used it.  Nor did you reference `$i` (`$f` in my version) which based on the `for` construct given above will contain the name of each file (or subdirectory) in `"$chosen_dir"`, in turn.

By the way, thanks for specifying that this is homework.  There could be much shorter solutions, but your general approach is fine if you fix the syntax errors and also **[quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943)**.

---

For the count of files within a subdirectory, you may not get an accurate count with the command you're using.  (Actually you'll *never* get an accurate count with the command: `ls "$chosen_dir" | wc -l` because you're not testing the subdirectory, you're testing the directory entered by the user.)  Rather than just `ls`, you might consider using `ls -1 -A "$i"` so that the line count will give an accurate count of the files within the subdirectory.  (See `man ls` for details on the `-1` and `-A` flags.)

This still won't correctly handle filenames that contain newlines, but for homework I highly highly highly doubt you will get any points off for that.  (Many scripts actually used in production also fail on filenames which contain newlines; such names pretty much only come from malicious users.)

---

I assume you can work out part C yourself.  ;)  (See `man sort` if you need to, and search the `sort` tag on this site also.)